# How do you restart a game on pygame by using a button?

Tags: python, pygame

I've completed a PyGame lesson and written all of the tutorial's code. And I'm presently working on a Restart button for the game, which basically allows you to re-play the game without having to re-run the code. I've created the button's class and made the button itself clickable; the only thing I'm lacking is a mechanism to restart the game by hitting the button.

```py
import pygame
import random
import math
from pygame import mixer
 
# Initialize PyGame
pygame.init()
 
# Create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
 
# Background
background = pygame.image.load('background.png')
 
# Background Music
mixer.music.load('background.wav')
mixer.music.play(-1)
 
# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
 
# Player
PlayerImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')
PlayerX = 370
PlayerY = 480
PlayerX_change = 0
 
# Enemy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6
 
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('enemy.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(100, 736))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(4)
    enemyY_change.append(40)
 
# Bullet
 
# Ready - You can't see the bullet on the screen
# Fire - The bullet is currently moving
 
bulletImg = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 2.5
bullet_state = "ready"
 
# Score
score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
 
textX = 10
textY = 10
 
# Game Over
over_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)
 
# Final Score
final_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 40)
 
 
# Restart Button
button_img = pygame.image.load('restart.png')
buttonX = 350
buttonY = 375
 
GameOver = False
 
 
def show_score(x, y):
    score = font.render("Score : " + str(score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))
 
 
def game_over_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(over_text, (200, 250))
 
 
def final_score_text():
    final_text = final_font.render("Final Score: " + str(score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(final_text, (260, 325))
 
 
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(PlayerImg, (x, y))
 
 
def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))
 
 
def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))
 
 
def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False
 
 
class Button():
        def __init__(self, x, y, image):
            self.image = image
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
 
        def draw(self):
 
            action = False
 
            # get mouse position
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
 
            # check if mouse is over the button
            if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
                if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                    action = True
 
            # draw button
            screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
 
            return action
 
 
# create restart button instance
button = Button(buttonX, buttonY, button_img)
 
# Game loop
running = True
while running:
 
    # RGB - Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
 
    # Background Image
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
 
    if GameOver is False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
 
            # If keystroke is pressed, check whether it's Right or Left
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord(','):
                    PlayerX_change = -7
                if event.key == ord('.'):
                    PlayerX_change = 7
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if bullet_state == "ready":
                        bullet_sound = mixer.Sound('laser.wav')
                        bullet_sound.play()
                        bulletX = PlayerX
                        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
 
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord(',') or event.key == ord('.'):
                    PlayerX_change = 0
 
        # Blits
        player(PlayerX, PlayerY)
        show_score(textX, textY)
 
        # Player Boundaries
        PlayerX += PlayerX_change
 
        if PlayerX <= 0:
            PlayerX = 0
        elif PlayerX >= 736:
            PlayerX = 736
 
        # Enemy Movement
 
        for i in range(num_of_enemies):
 
            enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
            if enemyX[i] <= 0:
                enemyX_change[i] = 3
                enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
            elif enemyX[i] >= 736:
                enemyX_change[i] = -3
                enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
 
            # Collision
            collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
            if collision:
                explosion_sound = mixer.Sound('explosion.wav')
                explosion_sound.play()
                bulletY = 480
                bullet_state = "ready"
                score_value += 100
                enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
                enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)
 
            enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i])
 
            # Bullet Movement
            if bulletY <= 0:
                bulletY = 480
                bullet_state = "ready"
 
            if bullet_state == "fire":
                fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
                bulletY -= bulletY_change
 
            # Game Over
            if enemyY[i] > 420:
                GameOver = True
 
    if GameOver is True:
        for j in range(num_of_enemies):
            enemyY[j] = 2000
        game_over_text()
        textY = 2000
        final_score_text()
        if button.draw() is True:
            print("Clicked")
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
 
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You have to add the relevant code to the question. A link to an off site resource is not sufficient. Off site resources tend to vanish. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Rabbid and thanks for editing my question, will sure be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function that initializes all game states. The function must set all the relevant variables in global name space (Use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt)):

```py
def init_game():
    global PlayerX, PlayerY, PlayerX_change
    global bulletX, bulletY, bulletX_change, bulletY_change, bullet_state
    global enemyImg, enemyX, enemyX, enemyX_change, enemyY_change, num_of_enemies

    PlayerX = 370
    PlayerY = 480
    PlayerX_change = 0

    bulletX = 0
    bulletY = 480
    bulletX_change = 0
    bulletY_change = 2.5
    bullet_state = "ready"

    enemyImg = []
    enemyX = []
    enemyY = []
    enemyX_change = []
    enemyY_change = []
    num_of_enemies = 6

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('enemy.png'))
        enemyX.append(random.randint(100, 736))
        enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
        enemyX_change.append(4)
        enemyY_change.append(40)
```

Call the function before the application loop. Call it again when you click the button:

```py
button = Button(buttonX, buttonY, button_img)

init_game()

# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    if GameOver is True:
        # [...]

        if button.draw() is True:
            print("Clicked")
            GameOver = False
            init_game()

    # [...]
```

Comment: Yea, I mistyped something at the button.draw() part. instead of 'GameOver = False' i typed 'Gameover == False'. But it's all good now, Thanks again for helping!